# How to generate statistics from postfix calculator results in java?

Tags: java, postfix-notation, rpn

I wrote a postfix calculator that takes value from keyboard and text files. It give error prompt if the expression is invalid. Now I need to generate some statistics from the evaluated expression results. Specifically six different statistics should be gathered and displayed once evaluation is complete.

- The highest overall result value.
- The lowest overall result value.
- The aggregate of all result values, i.e. all results added together.
- The average result value.
- The total number of invalid expressions.
- The total number of valid expressions processed.

Just prior to program termination, the statistics should be displayed as follows –

```
Evaluations complete
Highest result: 1024.5 
Lowest result: -120 
Aggregate result: 2212 
Average result: 340 
Invalid expressions: 6 
Valid expressions: 150
```

Note: If the number of valid expressions is zero, then the highest, lowest and average should be shown as n/a.

I'm struggling with this part and don't know where to start. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PostfixCalc {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filename = "";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press K for keyboard or F to read expressions from a file");
    String user_input = keyboard.nextLine();
    String[] ui = user_input.split(" ");
    if (ui[0].equals( "k") | ui[0].equals("K")) {
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Post-Fix Expression (eg: 5 2 *)");
            String postfix=keyboard.nextLine();
            String [] elements =postfix.split(" ");


            if (postfix.equals("")){
                System.out.println("Application Closed");
                keyboard.close();
                System.exit(0);
                }
            if (elements.length >=3){
                try{
                    float num1, num2;
                    num1 = Float.parseFloat(elements[0]);
                    num2 = Float.parseFloat(elements[1]);

                        if(elements[2].equals("+")){
                            System.out.println("Total: "+(num1 + num2));
                        }
                        else if(elements[2].equals("*")){
                            System.out.println("Total: "+(num1 * num2));
                        }
                        else if(elements[2].equals("/")){
                            System.out.println("Total: "+(num1 / num2));
                        }
                        else if(elements[2].equals("-")){
                            System.out.println("Total: "+(num1 - num2));
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Error Invalid Expression: "+ postfix);
                        }
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("Error Invalid Expresion: "+postfix);
                    }
                }
                else if  (elements.length <3) {
                    System.out.println("Error Invalid Expression: "+ postfix);
                }               
        }           
    } else if (ui[0].equals("f") || ui[0].equals("F")) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter file name eg: Demo.txt");
            filename = keyboard.nextLine();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            System.out.println("Processing " + filename);
            System.out.println();
            String line = s.nextLine();
            String array[] = line.split(" ");
            if (array.length >= 3) {
                try {
                    float array1, array2, total1, total2, total3, total4, array3, array5;
                    array1 = Float.parseFloat(array[0]);
                    array2 = Float.parseFloat(array[1]);
                    total1 = array1 + array2;
                    total2 = array1 * array2;
                    total3 = array1 / array2;
                    total4 = array1 - array2;

                    if (array[2].equals("+")) {
                        System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + line);
                        System.out.println(array1 + " " + array[2] + " " + array2 + " = " + total1);
                        System.out.println();
                    } else if (array[2].equals("*")) {
                        System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + line);
                        System.out.println(array1 + " " + array[2] + " " + array2 + " = " + total2);
                        System.out.println();
                    } else if (array[2].equals("/")) {
                        System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + line);
                        System.out.println(array1 + " " + array[2] + " " + array2 + " = " + total3);
                        System.out.println();
                    } else if (array[2].equals("-")) {
                        System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + line);
                        System.out.println(array1 + " " + array[2] + " " + array2 + " = " + total4);
                        System.out.println();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(" Error Invalid Expression: " + line);
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println(" Error Invalid Expresion: " + line);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            } else if (array.length < 3) {
                System.out.println(" Error Invalid Expression: " + line);
                System.out.println();
            }
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String nl = s.nextLine();
                String ar[] = nl.split(" ");
                if (ar.length >= 3) {
                    try {
                        float ar1, ar2, total1, total2, total3, total4;
                        ar1 = Float.parseFloat(ar[0]);
                        ar2 = Float.parseFloat(ar[1]);
                        total1 = ar1 + ar2;
                        total2 = ar1 * ar2;
                        total3 = ar1 / ar2;
                        total4 = ar1 - ar2;

                        if (ar[2].equals("+")) {
                            System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + nl);
                            System.out.println(ar1 + " " + ar[2] + " " + ar2 + " = " + total1);
                            System.out.println();
                        } else if (ar[2].equals("*")) {
                            System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + nl);
                            System.out.println(ar1 + " " + ar[2] + " " + ar2 + " = " + total2);
                            System.out.println();
                        } else if (ar[2].equals("/")) {
                            System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + nl);
                            System.out.println(ar1 + " " + ar[2] + " " + ar2 + " = " + total3);
                            System.out.println();
                        } else if (ar[2].equals("-")) {
                            System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + nl);
                            System.out.println(ar1 + " " + ar[2] + " " + ar2 + " = " + total4);
                            System.out.println();
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(" Error Invalid Expression: " + nl);
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println(" Error Invalid Expresion: " + nl);
                        System.out.println();
                    }

                } else if (array.length < 3) {
                    System.out.println(" Error Invalid Expression: " + nl);
                    System.out.println();
                }

            }

        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: That file does not exist, please re-enter: ");
            filename = keyboard.nextLine();
            Scanner s;

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Neither K or F have been entered");
        System.out.println("System Terminated");
        keyboard.close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What's your question? We're more than happy to help, but just make sure you help us as much as possible too! You might want to check out the help center to see out to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Is it your code ? what is your question ? You could add some println to trace what happens ...

Comment: Sorry if i didn't make it clear.. I want to generate statistics of all the results.. As in, after a few evaluations, the program should generate some  statistics, such as the highest value, lowest value, etc.

Comment: Consider splitting your code into methods, as it will ease out your implementation and make this statistics computation easier to add.

Answer (score 0):

During execution, you'll have to get the result of each processed operation in some kind of collection.

Then, once all operations have been processed, you compute those statistics and output them.

I won't be more precise as it appears to be some kind of homework.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you elaborate a bit with code, so I could understand a bit better. And this is not a homework, it is a part of my exercise. Thanks

Comment: homework is the generic StackOverflow name for exercise. If you take a look at ... say "java rpn calculator" questions, you'll se what your colleagues are working on ;-) I guess your teacher want us to gain some fake internet points from you, poor students.